# When will I stall?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises

Currently doing EMOM with 11 push ups per minute.

Started 1 janurary 2021 with 77 push ups in 7 minutes and now I'm at 121 in 11 minutes.
At the moment it's quite fairly easy, not easy like I could do way more than that but easy enough to know that I won't fall any set and I'm confident that I will be able to add 11 reps every day for maybe the next week.
But theoretically shouldn't it become easier?
By adding reps shouldn't every repetition eventually become so easy that adding 11 more makes no difference?
At the moment getting halfway to the sets is easy but then I really have to push hard not to hit my nose on the ground by failing a repetition.
I've seen people on youtube doing single sets of thousands of repetitions.

How likely is that I will be able to do 666 push ups in one hour before 2022? It's not like I'm giving up, just want to know what to expect.

How strong am I? I don't think I have many ways to test this... I can do 73 push ups in on single set. No gym here.

Comment: I'd say strength might not even be the limiting factor. You're going to stall when your elbows start feeling sore. Not the muscles, but the joints and tendons. See [tendinitis](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/tendinitis/symptoms-causes/syc-20378243). Also, this type of training is not conducive to building strength. All you're doing is building endurance. If you're truly serious about this goal, you should spend some time with a physical therapist to map out how best to proceed. This linear progression is a pipe dream no matter how you cut it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no way we can know when you will stall, and why.